# Static function and non-static variable

Tags: c++, static

In following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void StaticFunction(int variable){ }
    void NonStaticFunction() { }

private:
    int nonStaticVariable;
};
```

I need to get a 'variable' and use it in 'NonStaticFunction'

I have tried making 'nonStaticVariable' static and assign its value to 'variable', but then I still would have to use static variable in 'NonStaticFunction', which throws linker error.

```
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int A::staticVariable" (?staticVariable@A@@2IA)
```

Are there any ways of solving it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here... You want some data that is set for all instances of the class, and you need to use that data inside a (non-`static`) member function?

Comment: the error is not because you use a static variable in a non static function but because you have to **define** (i.e. to tell a compiler to allocate memory for it rather than declare it) your static variable by adding `int A::staticVariable;` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a *definition* for your static data member **at namespace scope**:

```
int A::nowStaticVariable; // Put an initializer if 0 is not OK for you
```

However, if your static function needs access to a non-static data member, and you're forced to make that data member static in order to make the whole thing work, that smells like bad design. Consider re-thinking it.

Comment: @Neomex Well, WinAPI is C, not C++. In such case, it's expectable interop code can be ugly.

Answer (score 2):

If you make `nonStaticVariable` static; i.e.

```
static int nonStaticVariable;
```

in your class then you need to provide storage for it (or the linker will complain). This is called *the definition*. Do this in a source file by writing

```
int A::nonStaticVariable;
```

Interestingly this is initialised to zero (unlike non-statics in C and C++ which are not initialised).

Conceptually, you need to do this because no object of class A instantiates the static variable since it's not an instance-level data member.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the parameter in your static function

```
class A
 {
  public:
      static void StaticFunction(int // you don't need it ){ }
     void NonStaticFunction() { }

 private:// it can't be static and private ????
      static int nonStaticVariable;
  };

    int A:: nonStaticVariable = 0 ;

  void A::StaticFunction(/*int v */){
    you can use directly your static variable and if you declared parameter in your function 
    v= nonStaticVariable;

  }
```